# How to compress multiple rows with concat

Tags: mysql, sql, string, concatenation, workbench

Say I have a table COG in a database and each COG in the COG table can be linked to one or more organisms in a second table. If I just join these, I end up duplicating the COG numerous times for each organism.

I would like to generate a query that would instead, put each organism linked to a given COG into a single string using concat_ws() (i.e. CSV format).

I tried using:
    GROUP BY concat_ws(',', organism.name)

But that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what didn't work about it?  Can you post your full query? Some sample data would also be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT c.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(o.name)
    FROM COG c
        INNER JOIN organism o
            ON c.ID = o.COG_ID
    GROUP BY c.ID;
```

Comment: You might need a `DISTINCT` if they need to remove an duplicate values.